# Selected Spinner Item getting replaced by First row in the spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have been working on a spinner which has a custom layout for the dropdown. Here's my problem, when I select, let's say the 2nd item in the drop down, it gets selected and the drop down closes. When I reopen the drop down, the first row remains the same but the second row gets renamed to the first row. But it tells when I print out a log.d into console, that position:2 was selected.

Here's my code,

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.inflate(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue));
        if(list.getIsRecent()){
            textView.setText("Most Recent ");
        } else {
            textView.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        }
        return textView;
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        boolean isRecent;
        isRecent = list.get(position).getIsRecent();
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, parent, false);
                savedSearchName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner_layout_text_view);


            btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner_layout_button);

            relativeLayoutContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_item_name_container);
            relativeLayoutContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"relativeLayoutContainer: setOnClickListener: position"+position);
                    Method method = null;
                    if(mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner != null) {
                        mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner.setSelection(position);
                        try {
                            method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
                            method.setAccessible(true);
                            method.invoke(mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner);
                        } catch (Exception  e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            if(isRecent){
                btnDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                savedSearchName.setText(list.get(position).getName() + "MOSTRECENT");
            } else {
                savedSearchName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
                btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //AlertDialog
                });
            }

        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Screenshots:
Initial Spinner
[image: Initial Spinner]

Spinner DropDown
[image: Spinner dropdown]

Position 1 selected: Qwerty
[image: position 1 selected: qwerty]

Reopening dropdown
[image: Reopening dropdown]

And No, this is not a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()`, you're using the convertView wrong. This can be either `null` or an old view that needs to be recycled. If it's `null`, you have to inflate a new view, as you're doing. If not, this is an old item that needs to be recycled (i.e. you need to modify the text, you don't even need to set text size and color again):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(parent);
            textView = (TextView) li.inflate(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
            textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.color.blue));
        }
        if(list.getIsRecent()){
            textView.setText("Most Recent ");
        } else {
            textView.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        }
        return textView;
    }
```

Also, getCustomView is storing btnDelete and savedSearchName in fields in your object, and probably this is messing up with old contents. Also, update the convertView always (now, if convertView is not null you don't update it):

```
public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    boolean isRecent;
    isRecent = list.get(position).getIsRecent();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView savedSearchName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner_layout_text_view);


    ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_spinner_layout_button);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_item_name_container);
    relativeLayoutContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"relativeLayoutContainer: setOnClickListener: position"+position);
            Method method = null;
            if(mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner != null) {
                mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner.setSelection(position);
                try {
                    method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    method.invoke(mSavedSearchCriteriaSpinner);
                } catch (Exception  e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });


    if(isRecent){
        btnDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        savedSearchName.setText(list.get(position).getName() + "MOSTRECENT");
    } else {
        savedSearchName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    //AlertDialog
            });
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

About storing `savedSearchName` and `btnDelete` in fields, I guess is because you want to avoid searching them again. In that case I'd suggest using a holder pattern. See for example *Hold View Objects in a View  Holder* in the following [Google guide](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the issue with drop down still persists. When I select item1, when reopening the drop down again, item0 is repeated twice.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read the example too fast. After reviewing it again, it looks like probably it's because you're storing `btnDelete` and `savedSearchName` in fields in your object in `getCustomView()`, and probably this is messing up with old contents. Also, update the view always (now, if convertView is not null you don't update it). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that was the issue. After using the ViewHolder pattern, the issue has been resolved.